# BigDecimal wrapper: to have a ZERO static field

Tags: java, static, wrapper

My custom `Money` class is a kind of wrapper of `BigDecimal` and `org.joda.money.Money` classes.

Same as `BigDecimal` has, I need a `Money.ZERO` to be used around my application (often in `reduce()` operations).

I have spotted that my `Money.ZERO` changes during my application execution (it is, its `amount` value might be non-ZERO) causing invalid results.

Here below is my custom `Money` class:

```
@Getter
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Money implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4274180309004444639L;

    public static final Money ZERO = new Money(BigDecimal.ZERO, CurrencyUnit.EUR);

    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Convert(converter = CurrencyUnitToStringConverter.class)
    private CurrencyUnit currency;

    public static Money of(BigDecimal amount, CurrencyUnit currency) {
        return new Money(amount, currency);
    }

    public Money add(Money addition) {
        checkCurrency(addition);

        amount = amount.add(addition.getAmount());
        return new Money(amount, currency);
    }

    public Money substract(Money reduction) {
        checkCurrency(reduction);

        amount = amount.subtract(reduction.getAmount());
        return new Money(amount, currency);
    }

    private void checkCurrency(Money other) {
        if (!Objects.equal(getCurrency(), other.getCurrency())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Currency does not match when adding amounts!");
        }
    }
```

So my goal is to have a `ZERO` field which amount keeps as `BigDecimal.ZERO` forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying internal state.

Look e.g. at your `add` method:

```
public Money add(Money addition) {
    checkCurrency(addition);

    amount = amount.add(addition.getAmount());
    return new Money(amount, currency);
}
```

In this method you are re-assigning `amount`, therefore changing the value of your current `Money` instance.

Here is a simple fix:

```
public Money add(Money addition) {
    checkCurrency(addition);

    BigDecimal newAmount = amount.add(addition.getAmount());
    return new Money(newAmount, currency);
}
```

The same applies to your `substract` method.

Comment: That it is! I didn't realise about `amount`. The missing `this.` confused me. Many thanks!

Comment: Not sure how (or if) Lombok can handle this, but ideally you would want to declare `amount` (and `currency`) as `final` to prevent similar surprises.

Comment: If you see on top of the class declaration, I did not put `@Setter` so there is no possible to change the values manually. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @lordneru The `BigDecimal` class is immutable which is why it can expose an application-wide constant such as `ZERO` and not encounter the problems you are in your question. Consider making your `Money` class immutable as well.

Comment: @lordneru: I was not talking about setters. I was talking about the _exact same issue_ that brought you here. Let the compiler help you where it can. Also: What @Slaw said. Read about immutability and how you can achieve that. Merely not having setters does not imply that no one will be able to modify values of your class (e.g. we cannot see how `CurrencyUnit` is defined).

Comment: I had issues while adding `final` to attributes as hibernates uses default constructor (`Money` is `@Embeddable`). So, I solved it just adding `@Immutable` annotation to the class. `Final` attributes are no longer necessary.